Cannot Extend UIApplication to Conform to Custom Protocol in Xcode 16
I am trying to extend UIApplication to conform to a custom protocol AppSwitcher for handling URL opening. This code worked fine in Xcode 15, but after upgrading to Xcode 16, it is causing errors.
public protocol AppSwitcher {
    func open(
        _ url: URL,
        options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey: Any],
        completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?
    )
}

extension UIApplication: AppSwitcher {}


n Xcode 16, I can no longer extend UIApplication to conform to my AppSwitcher protocol without encountering errors. It worked perfectly in Xcode 15.

Has anyone else experienced this in Xcode 16?
Is this a change in Swift 5.9 or the iOS SDK?
What’s the reason behind this change, and are there any workarounds to achieve the same result?


This is a change in the iOS SDK. The open method now has more annotations on its completion handler - @MainActor and @Sendable.
You should add those to your protocol method too.
public protocol AppSwitcher {
    @MainActor
    func open(
        _ url: URL,
        options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey: Any],
        completionHandler completion: (@MainActor @Sendable (Bool) -> Void)?
    )
}

Also consider using the async version of the open method in your protocol.
public protocol AppSwitcher {
    @MainActor
    func open(_ url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any]) async -> Bool
}

If this change breaks some other parts of your code, that means you were not using open in a concurrency-safe way in the first place.

FYI if you want to compile code in Xcode15 after updating on
func open(
    _ url: URL,
    options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey: Any],
    completionHandler completion: (@MainActor @Sendable (Bool) -> Void)?
)

you can use #if compiler(>=x.x.x)
for xcode 15.1 compiler is 5.9.2

/Applications/Xcode
15.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
--version swift-driver version: 1.87.3 Apple Swift version 5.9.2 (swiftlang-5.9.2.2.56 clang-1500.1.0.2.5) Target:
arm64-apple-macosx14.0

for xcode 16.1 compiler is 6.0.2

/Applications/Xcode
16.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
--version swift-driver version: 1.115 Apple Swift version 6.0.2 (swiftlang-6.0.2.1.2 clang-1600.0.26.4)

#if compiler(>=6.0.0)
func open(
    _ url: URL,
    options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey: Any],
    completionHandler completion: (@MainActor @Sendable (Bool) -> Void)?
)
#else
func open(
    _ url: URL,
    options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey: Any],
    completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)?
)
#endif


This is how i fixed the issue

Open Launcher file and replace open function with below code.


 @MainActor
    func open(
        _ url: URL,
        options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey: Any],
        completionHandler completion: (@MainActor @Sendable (Bool) -> Void)?
    )



2.Next open URLLauncherPlugin file and modify as below

Hope the problem will be solved. Thanks Sweeper. This helps to resolve the problem.
